# Barman backup: Backup failed issuing start backup command

Tags: postgresql, backup, barman

I have begun looking into using barman to perform my database backups however I have come across the following error:

> barman backup main-server

This command gives the following result:

> ERROR: Impossible to start the backup. Check the log for more details, or run 'barman check main-server'

When I then run:

> barman check main-server

I get the following:

```
Server main-server:
    WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)
    PostgreSQL: OK
    is_superuser: OK
    wal_level: OK
    directories: OK
    retention policy settings: OK
    backup maximum age: FAILED (interval provided: 1 day, latest backup age: No available backups)
    compression settings: OK
    failed backups: FAILED (there are 4 failed backups)
    minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 0 backups, expected at least 0)
    ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
    not in recovery: OK
    archive_mode: OK
    archive_command: OK
    continuous archiving: FAILED
    archiver errors: OK
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: Log info from calling barman backup main-server:

> barman.wal_achriver INFO: No xlog segments found from file archival for main-server.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to activate the wal reception:

```
barman receive-wal --create-slot main-server
```

Then, in function of the version of barman you are using, the following can solve your problem:

barman version < 2.2

```
barman switch-xlog --force --archive main-server
```

barman version > 2.1

```
barman switch-wal --force --archive main-server
```

Comment: This is only true if you are using streaming